# Serial port communications equipment file is working on Mac but not working on window

Tags: java

This is the code which is not running in windows but running in mac
`

```
public ReadWithoutTimings() {
        super();
        num = 1;
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) SearchPorts3P4P.selectedPortIdentifier.open("Read JSE3P4P", 2000);
            // serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Read1", 2000);
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

        try {
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);
        }
        try {
            in = serialPort.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
    }

    public class SerialReader implements Runnable {

        public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
            inputStream = in;
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            String inputLine = null;
            try {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long end = start + 120 * 1000;// 60 seconds * 1000 ms/sec
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            // series.put(num, inputLine);
                            // num++;

                            bw.write(inputLine);
                            bw.newLine();
                            bw.flush();
                            System.out.println(inputLine);

                            if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("DATE") | inputLine.trim().startsWith("REMARK")
                                    | inputLine.trim().startsWith("TESTED BY")) {
                                serialPort.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                br.close();
                                bw.close();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= end) {
                        serialPort.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        br.close();
                        bw.close();
                        PreviewJse3P4P.search.dispose();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please reconnect again");
                        PreviewJse3P4P.frame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                new CompareClass();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); //
         * System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); while
         * (portList.hasMoreElements()) { portId = (CommPortIdentifier)
         * portList.nextElement(); if (portId.getPortType() ==
         * CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) { if
         * (portId.getName().equals("/dev/cu.usbserial-FTCC026H")) { //
         * System.out.println("Connecting.....");
         * 
         * new ReadWithoutTimings(); } } }
         */

    }
}
`This is the code which is running in windows and mac 

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        //System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                 if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/cu.usbserial-FTCC026H")) {
                     System.out.println("Connecting.....");
            //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                    Read reader = new Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Read() {
        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Read", 2000);
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        try {
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    try {
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        try {
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
////////////////////////////////////put these lines to read line
            try {
                inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        readThread = new Thread(this);
        readThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
           byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
           String num = "";String temp = "";

            try {
                //put these lines to read line
                String inputLine=br.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine); 
                //////////////////////////////
            } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
            break;
        }
    }

    }
```

I made a program that select port from the combo box and press connect button and than send data. It's perfectly working on Mac but not working on window. I have put Rxtx.jar and rxtxSerial.dll to respective folder n jre but still it's not working. May be dll and jar file is not proper. Anybody is having dll & jar file for serial port communication for window. What is the problem not working with window. Even it's showing serial com port it means Rxtx.jar is working ,problem is with dll. Please tell me the reason and how to rectify.

Comment: i understand you have some native code in your application, you have to recompile the native code for Mac as mac won't support dll's, or if its a 3rd party library, you need to find the mac native library file (.so?) for the library

Comment: Yes, there is different library for Mac and window. For Mac it's .jnilib and for window it's .dll